# Confused about * and & with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

I'm working on a leetCode exercise to sum all the values in a BST that are within a certain range. However, I'm having trouble with some error messages. From my code I think it's pretty obvious what I'm trying to do but I'm not sure how to make it work.

```
/**
* Definition for a binary tree node.
* struct TreeNode {
*     int val;
*     TreeNode *left;
*     TreeNode *right;
*     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
* };
*/
class Solution {
int sol;
public:
int rangeSumBST(TreeNode* root, int L, int R) {
    sol = 0;
    helper(root, L, R, sol);
    return sol;
}
 void helper(TreeNode* node, int L, int R, int ans) {
    if (!(node = NULL)) {
        if (L <= node->val && node->val <= R)
            ans += node->val;
        if (L < node->val)
            helper(node->left, L, R);
        if (node->val < R)
            helper(node->right, L, R);
    }
}

};
```

I know I'm doing something wrong with pointers but I can't figure it out. Here's my error message...

```
solution.cpp: In member function helper
Line 23: Char 40: error: no matching function for call to 
'Solution::helper(TreeNode*&, int&, int&)'
             helper(node->left, L, R);
```

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It's in the rangeSumBST function where I call the helper function.

Comment: You are calling `helper` with 3 arguments, whereas your method takes 4 params

Comment: `void helper(TreeNode* node, int L, int R, int ans) {` What is the purpose of `ans` in this function? Note that you are passing by value here. Meaning if the value of `ans` changes the function calling it will not see the change.

Comment: Maybe you want helper to return an `int` instead of the `ans` parameter?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have much to do with pointers or with `*` or with `&`. It has to do with calling functions.

Your function `helper` takes a fourth argument `ans` (which should be a reference, by the way), but you did not pass that in your calls. You only passed three arguments.

You also keep setting `node` to `NULL` (use `==` not `=`!).

I suggest this:

```
void helper(TreeNode* node, int L, int R, int& ans) {
    if (!(node == NULL)) {
        if (L <= node->val && node->val <= R)
            ans += node->val;
        if (L < node->val)
            helper(node->left, L, R, ans);
        if (node->val < R)
            helper(node->right, L, R, ans);
    }
}
```

You might also consider *returning* the result rather than accumulating it in a reference argument, but that requires a few more changes to your function.

Answer (score 1):

Method 'Solution::helper' takes 4 parameters.